# Excel: Find and select multiple cells

Tags: excel

I am an excel noob with a massive and weirdly organized spreadsheet that contains several columns with hundreds of account number values.

I have identified 70 of these accounts that are "special" based on criteria not in this spreadsheet.  I wish to select EVERY cell containing one of the 70 identified account ID's but I cant figure out how to do this.  The Excel search function doesn't have any OR operator.

Is there a simple way to do this?  If not can someone please be really specific when describing the hard way to do it? I'm sure this can be done somehow.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Are the cells you need to select scattered over the sheet(s?), or in a single column?

Answer (score 0):

And in addition to Tim’s question: do you have the 70 accounts in a table somewhere? If so, you might be able to use VLOOKUP.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can just press Shift and click on every cell you want to selec withaut stopping pressing it.